# Solve linear equations:complicated A matrix definition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, julia

Question: How can I solve for `x` when `QWx + Ex = b`, where `Q`, `W`,and `E` are matrices, and `x` and `b` are vectors?

I have a system of equations that I would like to solve in Julia. I am new to Julia, but have a little experience in Java, and exposure to a few other languages.

The equations are of the form `A*x=b`, but with `A = (QW + E)`, where `Q`, `W`, and `E` are all predefined matrices of the correct dimensions.

I am new to Julia, and I'm pretty sure that it is just an issue of not knowing the correct words to search for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just `x=A\b` right, or is there some complication that I missed

Comment: It is just that.

The code I was following to reproduce some elements of it had a function to generate Q and W, so the call was actually an anonymous function. 

That had me confused for a while there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia uses `*` operator for matrix production and `+` for element wise addition, so first `A=W*Q+E` and then as @harold mentioned, `x=A\b` solves matrix division.

More details here ->
[JuliaLang doc for Linear Algebra](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg/)